# return the documents that match a given string in mongoose

Tags: javascript, express, mongoose

I'm trying to implement a search functionality in a MERN stack app where using the searchWord from the `req.params.searchWord` I will send the results that have the searchWord in them.

The code that I have now does what I want to. But, is it possible to use the functionality of the `filteredData` using the `aggregate` function of mongoose?

```
const getQuoteAuthorSearchedResult = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const searchWord = req.params.searchWord

    const uniqueQuoteAuthors = await QuoteModel.aggregate().group({
      _id: "$author",
      count: { $sum: 1 },
    });

    const filteredData = await uniqueQuoteAuthors.filter((value) => {
      return value._id.toLowerCase().includes(searchWord.toLowerCase());
    });

    res.status(200).json({
      results: filteredData
    })
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(401).json({ success: false });
  }
};
```

My data looks like this:

```
[
        {
            "_id": "Martin Luther King Jr",
            "count": 1
        },
        {
            "_id": "Friedrich Nietzsche",
            "count": 1
        },
        {
            "_id": "Marcus Tullius Cicero",
            "count": 1
        },
        {
            "_id": "Andre Gide",
            "count": 1
        },
        ...
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the [`$match`](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/aggregate.html#Aggregate.prototype.match()) pipeline stage and [`$regex`](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/query/regex/) query operator to filter the grouped data.

Besides, use `$option: 'i'`

> Case insensitivity to match upper and lower cases

E.g.

```
import mongoose from 'mongoose';
import { config } from '../../config';

mongoose.set('debug', true);

const quoteSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    author: String,
});
const QuoteModel = mongoose.model('quote', quoteSchema);

(async function main() {
    try {
        await mongoose.connect(config.MONGODB_URI);
        await Promise.all([QuoteModel].map((m) => m.collection.drop()));
        // seed
        await QuoteModel.create([
            { author: 'Nick' },
            { author: 'Nick' },
            { author: 'Jack' },
            { author: 'John' },
            { author: 'Alex' },
        ]);

        const searchWord = 'CK';

        const uniqueQuoteAuthors = await QuoteModel.aggregate()
            .group({
                _id: '$author',
                count: { $sum: 1 },
            })
            .match({ _id: { $regex: searchWord, $options: 'i' } });

        console.log('uniqueQuoteAuthors: ', uniqueQuoteAuthors);
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
    } finally {
        await mongoose.connection.close();
    }
})();
```

Output:

```
uniqueQuoteAuthors:  [ { _id: 'Jack', count: 1 }, { _id: 'Nick', count: 2 } ]
```